# Call a Python function and pass windows parameters from cmd.exe

Tags: python, windows, cmd, registry, contextmenu

I have a Python function that I want to run from the context-menu. I am using the Windows Registry to call the function when a file is right clicked, and I want the function to receive the file selected.

The context menu item looks something like [the `Random Commands` option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ht3k6.png).

The function I wish to run is `foo1()` in the file `test1`:

```py
# in script test1.py

def foo1():
    import sys
    print(sys.argv)
```

I tried approaching the problem using the python `-c` switch to directly call the function:

> ```
> python -c "import test1; test1.foo1()" %1
> ```

However, the value of `sys.argv` after selecting the file and executing is `['-c']`, which doesn't include the file selected.

I also tried using an argument parser to dynamically import and run the function:

```py
# in file registry_parser.py

import argparse
import os
import sys


if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('-n', '--func_name')
    parser.add_argument('-f', '--file_name')
    parser.add_argument('-p', '--file_path')

    args = vars(parser.parse_args())
    sys.path.insert(0, args['file_path'])

    exec(f"import {args['file_name']}")
    exec(f"{args['file_name']}.{args['func_name']}(sys.argv)")
```

And the function I would call from the registry is (paths simplified):

```py
registry_parser.py --func_name foo1 --file_name test1 --file_path "[PATH TO registry_parser.py]" %1
```

However, I either get an error `registry_parser.py: error: unrecognized arguments: %1` or the "`%1`" is parsed quite literally and ends up as a value in sys.argv.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So on all the forums I asked I never received a correct answer, but I found this [Reddit Post](https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/oixmu/add_entry_to_windows_7_context_menu_that_runs/) that has an example to a solution. Hope this helps someone else.